# How to know when the Winlogon desktop is ready for inputs?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, service, winlogon

I successfully used [SendSAS](https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/windows/desktop/dd979761.aspx) in a service (Local System Account). I call the API four seconds after the service starts. It seems that whatever the boot process duration, Windows manage to cache (sort of) the call: the same code finally shows me a logon screen a few seconds after the power on, on a fast laptop (Win10), and also shows me the logon screen after a very much longer delay on a slow Server (2012R2) running virtualized (wmware).

I am also able to use [CreateProcessAsUser](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682429.aspx) (with an updated token) to inject a tiny executable in the Session 1, Station WinSta0, Desktop Winlogon. The process then uses [SendInput](https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/windows/desktop/ms646310.aspx) to "auto-logon" the session (yes, this is an awful think to do do, I am aware of that).

My problem: if the tiny process starts "too early", nothing happens. If the service waits, say, 2 minutes, all is OK.

What API should I use (in the service or in the started process) to find out when the WinLogon desktop is ready to accept keyboard inputs?

I tried [WTSGetActiveConsoleSessionId](https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/aa383835.aspx) (in the service) and [OpenInputDesktop](https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/windows/desktop/ms684309.aspx) (in the process) hopping that failure would indicate the need to wait, but with no avail.

Comment: *if the tiny process starts "too early", nothing happens* - but are process started ok ? if yes, may be wait (if need) inside this process but not in service ?

Comment: CreateProcessAsUser always succeeds. I am ok with a wait, but how long?waiting for what?

Comment: Windows has its own built-in auto-logon capabilities, why are you doing this in code at all?

Comment: I am doing this code because I am told to do it by my management.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When your process starts in session 1, attached to the `WinSta0\Winlogon` desktop, you can periodically test the `Control Type` of the currently `IUIAutomationElement` focused element.

The APIs to use are : [IUIAutomation::GetFocusedElement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee671540.aspx)  and then [IUIAutomationElement::GetCurrentPropertyValue](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee696040.aspx) for the `UIA_ControlTypePropertyId` property. When you successfully get a focused element of type `UIA_EditControlTypeId`, the Windows logon screen is ready to accept inputs.

Don't forget to add a `Sleep` call between each try.

Tested OK with Windows Server 2008R2 and 2012R2, and with Windows 10.

Comment: On Windows 10, the user is already selected, so you can only enter Password. What if you want to login a different User then currently displayed?

Comment: @tunafish24 Then, you have to enumerate the UIA Elements currently displayed and you have to find the "Button" which allows to logon as another user...

Comment: @tunafish24 The relevant COM interface is IUIAutomationTreeWalker.

Comment: basically I have to enumerate all elements (Users) on the logon screen, simulate click on appropriate user and then enter the respective password?

Comment: No, you just have to click on the button/link saying "logon as another user", and then enter the userid and the password

Comment: The default setting in Windows 10, shows the list of users on left side of logon screen. The option to enable "logon as another user" needs to be configured in registry.

Comment: Ok. Then, you'll need to "recognize" what type of login screen you're currently on, and act on it... this can be quite complex.